# Bigger ProjectServer farm is performing worse

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, microsoft-project

I am using **Project Server 2007 sp3** with **SharePoint 2007 sp3** and **SQL Server 2008 r2**.

I have recently moved my farm from 2 servers (1 DB and 1 App/Web) to a very big farm having Many Servers, Clustered Database, Load Balancer, Powerful processors and Large RAM. This Farm has **more than one** Web Servers, Project App Servers, SharePoint App Servers and a separate Index Server.

But the **performance of Project Server in the new Farm has been downgraded**. Views are taking even more time to load data and Project publishing time has also been increased. I am also facing deadlock problems which are causing the project server queue jobs to fail.

Could anyone inform me that what would be the reason of this problem and what should be the starting point to look into the issue? Is it mainly because now the application server needs to communicate with other application servers which were not needed in the previous farm?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your new setup implies more network communication. Before, there was only network between sharepoint & database server. Latency can be an issue as many exchange are done.

What i would check:

- Put all Physical servers (DB first) in high profile static mode (power usage in bios).
- Check all network drivers are up to date (going directly to broadcom & intel web site)
- Check for antivirus exclusions
- If using proxy, check that root certificates are up to date
- Apply SQL maintenance plan to rebuild all indexes

Are client remote from this farm or on same lan ?
What about publishing from project pro ?